# Issue on using both I2C and Serial simultaniously in raspberry pi 2

Tags: serial-port, raspberry-pi, i2c

Currently, I am working on a project that need both Serial port and I2C of the raspberry pi (it's a raspberry pi 2) simultaneously. I am having an issue when communicating with the serial port while I2C data read. The data from the I2C will corrupt when communicating with serial port.

The serial port is connected to SIM800L and I2C port is connected to MPU6050 gyro.

Can someone explain this issue ?

The below image contains the error readings from the gyro (right side window) when try to send command to serial port (left side window)

[image: Data corruption]

Comment: Apparently you think this is somekind of hardware issue.  But that is unlikely.  The most probable cause is your method, which you fail to describe.  All you have done is state your conclusion, i.e. there is "corruption".

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply.
Actually I am not saying this is an hardware issue an I am not coming to any conclusion. Right now, I don't know how to resolve this issue. What I did was, I connected MPU6050 gyro to I2C pins in Rpi and SIM 800L to Serial Port. While receiving data from MPU6050 if I type something to SIM800L (using minicom), data from MPU6050 gets crashed. Also I am using MPU6050 demo code from jeff rowberg to test this.